# What type of SQL is used in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: sql, toad, ansi-sql

I'm new to using Toad for Oracle, so I hope my question makes sense.
As far as I know there is 'base' SQL which is ANSI SQL and from that there are proprietary versions such as PLSQL for Oracle and TSQL for Microsoft. Is that correct?

So when I'm using Toad, there is an option there that says Desktop: SQL or PLSQL and I can choose which one. So if I chose SQL, does that mean I need to use ANSI SQL only? What does that option do?

Thanks

Comment: PL/SQL is not a type of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "SQL" refers strictly to the query language. It's still Oracle's flavor of SQL.

"PL/SQL" refers to Oracle procedural extension of SQL. This allows you to write functions or procedures that run SQL natively, as well as too run procedural blocks that contain SQL (anonymous blocks).

For Toad, the distinction is really a matter of how the editor is configured. You can run PL/SQL in the SQL editor and vice versa. Remember, Toad is just an IDE, it can't change the way Oracle interprets SQL anymore than Eclipse can change the way Java compiles code.

Answer (score 1):

TOAD for Oracle or SQL Server, etc are just database client programs. They utilise the database back-engine, which means the SQL is exactly the same as if you were using PL/SQL or SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server. However, the TOAD clients are far more superior than the native client programs provided by Oracle or Microsoft. They come with a rich suite of tools and features to make your DBA experience far easier to manage, especially when it comes to SQL design, export and import, plus reporting features. TOAD is now owned by Dell Inc.

Comment: The "native client" program for SQL Server is arguably [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) (okay, it's not a small CLI application like `isql`, which I am ignoring as SSMS is available) and it's "pretty good". Now, Oracle's SQL\*Plus *:shudder:* ..

Comment: SQL*Plus ... noooooo you'll start the nightmares again

Comment: That's why you guys should get TOAD. I've never looked back.